# Python OpenCV - Crop image to area with gray background

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

It is quite hard to explain what I want in the title. I'll show what I need with an example or input/output. I have an image called 'image.jpg' that'll be an image with random strokes of different shades of black and dark-blackish gray on a white background and on one area it'll be a light grey background

[image: 1]

I want to use python's opencv and maybe PIL if it's useful and crop the image so I'll only see the gray area. So after whatever code I'll do it'll look like this image here

[image: 2]

That's it, appreciate all help here. I don't seem to know where to start here so I can't include whatever code I tried.

Comment: thresholding, maybe some morphology operations, get bounding box -- to start, I'd recommend that you browse the tutorials contained in opencv's documentation

Comment: if the gray is one specific shade (compared to the black and the white) then you could probably identify this yourself by scanning across horizontals and down verticals and this might be faster...

Comment: Where did the image originate? And does it have to be JPEG - which is lossy and changes the values. If it is a computer-generated image maybe you can save it as a PNG, then all the grey pixels will likely be **exactly** the same colour and easier to find.